# Android wifi-direct api for support Multi-group Networks

Tags: android, wifi-direct

My application need to create multi-group wifi-direct communication.But after testing I find that none of the following scenarios are feasible in Android:

1) a device plays the role of P2P client in one group and GO in another. 
2) a device behaves as client in two or more groups.

I want to ask does the google have the plan to update the android Wifi-Direct API for suppporting one of above, so that we could implement multi-group communication easily?

Or are there some ways for two wifi-direct group communication with each other in android?

Thanks!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer for all questions would be: No. though the second question it would be that As far as I know, No.

Anyway, if your logic requires you to be able to be GO & Client same time, then you could work around this by creating normal access point, where clients would connect to, and you could connect to other devices access point.

For access point, you could for example use the CreateGroup function, which would create hidden access point. Then you could use the Wifi Direct service advertising for delivering the password & SSID alongside IP-Address to other devices, so they could discover access points and connect to them.